# Restrict Product2 records visibility globally - country basis (controlled by user's Role / Country Code)

Tags: product

I want to hide Product2 records from country basis. I have a custom field called Country code in Product2 and user object.I am not able to handle this using pricebook object.  Here are the tasks I need to achieve related to product records.

1. User can only see his/her country product records.
2. Global search shouldn't return other country products.

Would it possible to restrict? Please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to this is **NO** - there is no way to implement OOB a private sharing model for `Product2` that you extend with criteria-based sharing

See [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp8VAAS) that you can vote up (7 years old)

Workaround is VF wherein the search option you provide to look up products on pages is country-aware (this would not help though with Global Search).  Or, use country-specific pricebooks

Comment: But product will still be visible on global search. Is there any way we can restrict from that?

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria - not that I know of; I'd question the business requirements